# extract file content greater than datetime.now

Tags: c#, file

I have a file with content like below,

`2018-02-28 10:00:00,A1, A2
 2018-02-28 10:05:00,A3, A4
 2018-02-28 10:10:00,A5, A6
 2018-02-28 10:00:00,A7, A8`

Now I would like get all the file content (as a different file) from date/time greater than `2018-02-28 10:05:00`?

I am able to check modified files after certain data,

```
var files = directory.GetFiles().Where(file=>file.LastWriteTime >= datetine.now);
```

But how to get content ?

Comment: Did you check the methods of `file`? Why the question? Did you try to read data from a file and failed?

Comment: you can loop on files and do `File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the OP is already looping on files and doesn't need to use the `File` methods. `file` is a FileInfo that already provides the appropriate methods

Comment: Use [FileInfo.OpenText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the content as text. Use [OpenRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.openread(v=vs.110).aspx) to read it as a binary stream. [MoveTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto(v=vs.110).aspx) to move to a new location. [CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e105zt(v=vs.110).aspx) to copy it

Comment: thanks, any sample code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos obviously there are multiple ways to do  one thing

Comment: @EhsanSajjad and the OP is doing what you mentioned already. I suspect Tim Schmelter guessed the *actual* question. How to filter the *rows*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos pardon me, OP is not reading files right now just getting the list, question is how to get file's  content

Comment: @EhsanSajjad read Tim's answer. The question makes sense in that light. Otherwise it would be a duplicate of quite a few other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this (using C#7 out variable feature):

```
var fileContents = directory.GetFiles()
    .Select(f => new
    {
        File = f,
        Content = File.ReadLines(f.FullName)
                    .Select(l => new{ Line = l, Fields = l.Split(',') })
                    .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Line, x.Fields,
                DateStr = x.Fields[0].Trim(),
                IsValid = DateTime.TryParse(x.Fields[0].Trim(), out var date),
                Date = date
            })
            .Where(x => x.IsValid && x.Date > DateTime.Now)
            .ToArray()
    });
```

Comment: In retrospect, yes, the OP seems to want to filter rows.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, Thanks for the code, perfect working

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
           string input = "2018-02-28 10:00:00,A1, A2\n" +
                          "2018-02-28 10:05:00,A3, A4\n" +
                          "2018-02-28 10:10:00,A5, A6\n" +
                          "2018-02-28 10:00:00,A7, A8";

           DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
           var results = input.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(x => x.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
               .Select( y => new { date = DateTime.Parse(y.First()), colA = y.Skip(1).First(), colB = y.Last() })
               .Where(x => x.date <= now).ToList();
```